# CORS bloquea el método FETCH en JavaScript Nativo (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, cors

Estoy haciendo un fetch a una API, un método súper sencillo, solamente debo imprimir en un console.log el json que trae el api, pero por algún motivo me bloquea CORS, no he podido solucionarlo, adjunto código de FETCH y el código de error, saludos.

```
function getDepartments() {

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://helpdeskwebservices.tk/api/Departamentos", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

}

getDepartments();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La API es tuya también, en que está desarrollada?

Comment: De un compañero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede porque no tienes configurado el CORS dentro de tu API.

Te muestro de esta manera ya que actualmente con esta cuenta no puedo comentar.

Si lo estas trabajando como en este video: [Configuracion cors](https://youtu.be/KK7fJTXxeeE) te servirá lo siguiente.

## Configuración CORS#

```
string policy = "MyPolicy";

//Configurando Corse
builder.Services.AddCors(Options =>
{
    Options.AddPolicy(name: policy, build =>
    {
        build.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost")
        .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

//Agregando politica de corse a la app
app.UseCors(policy);
```

Comment: Eso es en ASP.NET verdad estimado Geovanny, saludos.

Comment: @DanielRivas si así es.

Comment: Gracias amigo, funcionó, saludos.

Comment: Me alegro mucho, bendiciones.